# Installing Pillow error: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, linux, gcc, python-imaging-library

While i try to install Pillow 2.5.3
I am getting an error : command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

[Here is the complete log of what happened](http://pastebin.com/5k2TsyJY)

I need this library as a part of another python project.
I have gone through many solutions but none helped me

Comment: Might be the same issue as here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41492878/command-x86-64-linux-gnu-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1/42690573#42690573](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41492878/command-x86-64-linux-gnu-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1/42690573#42690573)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are missing Python headers.  Install `python-dev` from your distribution's package manager.

Equally for python 3. Install `python3-dev`, example:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried `python-dev` package but not worked for me.
Then i have tried below code work like charm

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running python 3.6 the use this command

> sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev