# Docker/Linux: 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, linux, docker, ubuntu

I have this error when trying to load my docker container, specifically when trying to install the `pyodbc` package.

I have tried all the fixes here: [command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41492878/command-x86-64-linux-gnu-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1)

but I still get the following error:

```
#17 14.20     In file included from src/buffer.cpp:12:
#17 14.20     src/pyodbc.h:56:10: fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory
#17 14.20        56 | #include <sql.h>
#17 14.20           |          ^~~~~~~
#17 14.20     compilation terminated.
#17 14.20     error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

My dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install python3-dev -y
RUN apt-get install python3-pip -y
RUN apt-get install libssl-dev -y
RUN apt-get install build-essential -y
RUN apt-get install libffi-dev -y
RUN apt-get install libsnappy-dev -y
RUN apt-get install lib32ncurses5-dev -y
RUN apt-get install libpcap-dev  -y
RUN apt-get install libpq-dev -y

COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip3 install python-snappy

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app

ENTRYPOINT [ "python3" ]

CMD [ "app.py" ]
```

Comment: Note: apt-get install accepts multiple packages on one line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `apt-get install unixodbc-dev -y` before install `pyodbc`, the `sql.h` is in that package, see next:

```
/# dpkg -L unixodbc-dev | grep sql.h
/usr/include/sql.h
```

Comment: That did it! I am not sure how I would have figured this out otherwise.